# Polynominal time reduction transitiviy proof

Tags: algorithm

I am just trying to see if anyone can clear up what "alphabet" means in the following statement.

"Recall: for a polynomial-time reduction ≤p, L ≤p M means that there is a computable
function f: alphabet of L→alphabet of M such that x∈L iff f(x)∈M."

It is in a proof for the transitivity of polynomial reduction.

Comment: They're talking about the set of input symbols.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_(computer_science)) is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

An alphabet is the set of symbols from which a language (L or M in this case) is constructed.